# Sqlite database does not return PRIMARY field value

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite DB. I'm using SQLite3 extension to connect to it in PHP.

Database was from a program I used until now for invoices. I took out sqlite file from that program and wrote own web based inteface.

Everything seems to be ok, except when I created new table to existing database.

Database was created, I could add new entries and lastInsertRowid() gave back proper Last Insert IDs.

However, when I started to select entries from new table, all IDs (Primary key) were empty.

I opened my database with a SQLite Database browser and something is odd.

Maybe first I will give my db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS koszty
(
    id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY DESC,
    data NUMERIC,
    nazwa TEXT,
    wartosc_netto NUMERIC UNSIGNED,
    podatek NUMERIC UNSIGNED,
    typ NUMERIC UNSIGNED,
    filename TEXT,
    opis TEXT
)
```

When I opened DB there is strange table sqlite_autoindex_koszty_1 that seems to correspond to table only. Old tables does not have it.

On the other hand There is also sqlite_sequence table that seems to store autoincrement ids.

All tables have their name here and AI value except for koszty.

What could be a reason? How to fix DB. Is it me doing something wrong (maybe Sqlite versions are different? using SQLite3 on Sqlite2 DB?) or is SQLite so inconsistent?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me, found it. 
Field definition should be:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
```

instead of

```
id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY DESC,
```

Without autoincrement it creates index for Primary key instead of Autoincrement it.

Strange behaviour I must say.

Comment: The [AUTOINCREMENT](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) keyword is not needed. The important part is the `INTEGER`.

Comment: But with Integer it worked exacly same. created additional index table. First definition was: "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DESC" which gave me the problem i described above. Later i changed it to Numeric which did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To make one of your columns autoincrementing, you must declare it as [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (not NUMERIC).
If you have no such column, the value returned by `lastInsertRowid` is for the hidden `rowid` column.

The `sqlite_autoindex_` object is not a table but the internal index created for your primary key.

Comment: Yeah, integer was first one I used earlier, wasn't good too so changed it to NUMERIC. It was missing autoincrement keyword mainly I think. Thx for answer!